# Flex List limit number of elements

Tags: apache-flex, list, hide, element

Is it possible to define a property to limit the number of elements which will appear in a mx:List ? I've read about setting the property rowCount, but I don't see any effect.
Can a filter be applied to accomplish this? My intention was to avoid removing the items from the list/array collection, but simply "hide" them. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different option is to use a new arraycollection and get your limited items from your big arraycollection :

```
//get first 10 elements
myArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( myBigArrayCollection.toArray().slice(0,9) );
```

if you want to work with pagers, you could hold a counter where you keep track of what page the user is on, and get the next elements from you big array collection. example:

```
//this is just a (very) simple example
//page = integer (counter) for knowing which page the user is on
page = 0;
page_low = page*10;
page_high = page_low + 9;
myArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( myBigArrayCollection.toArray().slice(page_low,page_high) );
```

(still using a filter is a more elegant solution)

Answer (score 2):

You can "hide" items from display in a List-based class, without modifying your underlying source data, by using a Collection class, such as an ArrayCollection, and filtering the data.

Read these [docs on Collection filtering](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_4.html).

To quote:

> You use a filter function to limit the data view in the collection to
>   a subset of the source data object. The function must take a single
>   Object parameter, which corresponds to a collection item, and must
>   return a Boolean value specifying whether to include the item in the
>   view. As with sorting, when you specify or change the filter function,
>   you must call the refresh() method on the collection to show the
>   filtered results. To limit a collection view of an array of strings to
>   contain only strings starting with M, for example, use the following
>   filter function:

```
public function stateFilterFunc(item:Object):Boolean
{
    return item >= "M" && item < "N";
}
```

Comment: Him thanks for the comment. However, I want to filter items based on their positions. In a certain view I want to show the first 20, and the other view I want to show all of them. Can I filter based on this?

Comment: @Rui I don't know what "Filter based on their positions" means.  If you can define it; you can probably code it.  Are you using the same dataProvider for two separate lists?

Comment: I'm already filtering items by date. On one state, I want my list to present the first 20 items, on other state I want to show all of them.

Comment: You can use originalCollection.getItemIndex(item) < 20 as your condition in the filter function.  Also to note rowCount I believe is a way to set the height on the component based on how many rows you want visible before having to scroll.